# Continuity of the function $f$ defined by $f(x,y)=1$ if $xy=0$ and $f(x,y)=2$ otherwise

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Define $f:\mathbb R^{2}\to \mathbb R$ by  $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if } xy=0\\2 &\text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$

Let $S$ be the set of all those points of $\mathbb R^{2}$ at which $f$ is continuous. Then $S$ is

(a) open

(b) closed

(c) connected ?

I have only problem about finding $S$. I think it is whole of $\mathbb R^{2}$. If I am right then it is OK. But if I am wrong then I want to know at which points $f$ is discontinuous and why?

Comment: No, $f$ is not continuous on all of $\Bbb R^2$. Can you give a verbal description of the set of points where $f(x,y)=1$?

Comment: I can't give..Please give

Comment: $xy=0$ if and only if $x=0$ or $y=0$, so $f(x,y)=0$ precisely on the coordinate axes. Everywhere off the axes it's $2$. That should make it very easy to tell where $f$ is discontinuous.

Comment: On the co-ordinate axes $f(x,y)=1$

Comment: Yes, that's true; are you saying that $f$ is discontinuous on the axes and continuous everywhere else?

Comment: Yes..Only discontinuity on the axes

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And knowing that should make it pretty easy to answer the actual question.